# How to use `expect`、`spawn`、`send`、`interact` in Arch Linux or in Manjaro?

Tags: linux, shell, archlinux, manjaro

As question, I want to write a script to login server without password typed in , as below:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set pw "mypasswd"
spawn ssh user@10.2xx.1yy.2zz
expect "Password"
send "$pw"
interact
```

Now, when I execute this script, the errors as below:

```
/usr/local/bin/lx:line6: spawn：command not found
/usr/local/bin/lx:line8: expect：command not found
/usr/local/bin/lx:line9: send：command not found
/usr/local/bin/lx:line10: interact：command not found
```

And, I tried the `pacman -S expect`, some package is installed, but my script is still not effecitve.

How should I install the commands in my Manjaro Linux?

Comment: `pacman -Syu` then `pacman -S expect` to update your system and then install the `expect` package. This questions is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I tried the `pacman -S expect`, some package is installed, but my script is still not effecitve.

Comment: I'm not sure what provides `spawn` and `send`, but the expect package provides `/usr/bin/expect`. What other package are you interacting with that have `spawn` and `send`?

Comment: `spawn` and `send` are `expect` commands.

Comment: @Shawn.X how are you executing your script? The errors you're getting ("Command not found") suggest that you're not actually running the expect script with expect.

Comment: @larsks -- thank you.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, Hi sir, `spwan` starts/kick offs a process for command which we do mention inside it(in this case it is ssh) and sends expect command will expect string/data whenever a process is kicked off, in this case ssh will usually ask something like `test#Please enter pa etc etc` so it looks for it once this is fulfilled then send will take care of sending value to it, basically we try to make automatic authentication. Though I am not a big fan of expect to very honest, cheers sir.

Comment: @larsks just `bash myscript.sh`

Comment: You don't have a bash script. You can't run it with `bash`. You have an `expect` script. You should name it `myscript.expect`, not `myscript.sh`, and would run it as `expect -f myscript.expect`.

Comment: @larsks I set shell `#!/usr/bin/expect` in the head of my script.

Comment: That doesn't do anything at all if you run your script as `bash myscript.sh`. You are saying "run this with bash", which, as discussed, isn't going to work.

Comment: @larsks it works, thanks!